# How to Boot 2nd Gen Zenbook by USB and Install Debian?

Tags: boot, system-installation, grub, zenbook

I am trying to install Linux Debian 8.5 (dd'ed it successfully to USB stick) on SD card of Zenbook UX303UA. However, Grub is 1 version. I cannot boot from the USB and there exists no menu option for the fetaure in the ultrabook. I accessed the Bios by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> at the login, since it does not start naturally by USB and does not give me a list boot options. I think the USB is at `/dev/sdb1` now so one option is to configure Grub directly. Fig. 1 Bios and Boot, Fig. 2 Bios, USB configuration and Advanced

[image]
[image]

### Iterating GAD3R's proposal

Disable successfully *Fastboot* in Bios Boot. 
Fig. 4 After pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> at login when *Fastboot* disabled*,

[image]

Fig. (5-7) are about unsuccessfully setting up boot by USB

1. first rename the option as *USB* or whatever, since just name (Fig. 5)
2. it requires the location of the boot there (Fig. 6)
3. I cannot find any other location than the current USB SSD (Fig. 7)

Fig. 5 Renaming as *USB* in Boot , Fig. 6 You cannot Enable Legacy Boot for some reason (Why?), Fig. 7-10 You cannot find right location for new boot option

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I cannot find a way to boot from USB.

### 2nd Iteration

I disable *Secure Boot* in Security > Boot. I enable CSM. 
I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> at the login. 
I get the list of items to boot from.

- My test USB works
- My Debian installer does not work so this confirms it is faulty.

Problem solved!

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit Linux kernel 4.7
Grub: version 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug in your USB drive

Turn on your pc

Enter UEFI through pressing ESC or F2

From the **Boot** tab  Disable Fastboot

( Enable Launch CSM if you need to boot the Legacy mode)

Press F10 to save & exit

Press ESC or F2 again

In **Boot** tab your USB drive should be listed.

Change the order

Press F10 to save & exit

Your should now boot from the USB drive

**Edit**

You need to go to **security** tab, **secure boot menu** and choose **disabled**

Comment: Please, see the body for my iterations of your proposal. I cannot get USB listed. I cannot enable CSM for some reason.

Comment: go to security >> secure boot menu >> disabled